# Deleting a file from offline app cache

Tags: iphone, html, caching

Just a quick hypothetical before I get too far on this project!

When creating an offline app for a mobile device like the iPhone, does deleting a reference to a file in the manifest delete it from the cache on the next update?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the ui won't display the changes without an additional refresh. You can avoid this by listening for the updateready event on page load. Here's some sample code from the HTML5Rocks website:

```
// Check if a new cache is available on page load.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
  // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
  // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
  window.applicationCache.swapCache();
  if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
} else {
  // Manifest didn't changed. Nothing new to server.
}
}, false);

}, false
```

[Here's a link for more info.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: Thanks! I was mainly unsure about what would become of resources I no longer needed. Just wanted to make sure I didn't need to programmatically clean up after myself. I didn't want to bloat up the cache with no longer linked images, for example!